# UITextField inside UIPopover

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have a UITextField inside a UIPopover. However, no matter what I do, I cant type in it. The UITextField works fine  if I use it  in the main view controller.

code:

```
UITextField *usernameTextField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(166.0, 847.0, 100.0, 51.0)];
usernameTextField.secureTextEntry=NO;
[usernameTextField setPlaceholder:@"Username"];
[usernameTextField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
[usernameTextField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
[usernameTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
[usernameTextField setClearsContextBeforeDrawing:YES];
[usernameTextField setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[usernameTextField setEnabled:YES];
usernameTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
usernameTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
usernameTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0];
usernameTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
usernameTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
usernameTextField.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:usernameTextField];
```

Any idea, whats wrong ?

Comment: Does self.view have userInteractionEnabled set to yes?

Comment: yup. as you can see from the code.

Comment: No, there is no code relating to the creation of `self`.

Comment: You do understand that I am asking about the view that you are adding the textField to and not asking about the textField,  right?

Answer (score 1):

Is the textfield in its own view with a view controller? If not, you can try that and then initialize the UIPopoverController with the view controller like: [[UIPopOverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: yourViewControllerwithTextField];

Comment: yes, it is in its own viewcontroller and I have already done what you mentioned !

Comment: I am doing it programmatically. I see the textfield on the popover.